# Xpath for two different attributes in 2 different tags

Tags: html, xpath, qtp

### **HTML Snippet:**

```
<TH class="abcd" style="WIDTH: 70%">03 Mar 2014</TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 58%" height=18>27 Feb 2014</TH>
<TH class="abcd" style="WIDTH: 70%">03 Jun 2014</TH>
<TH style="WIDTH: 58%" height=18>12 Jun 2014</TH>
```

### **Description:**

We need to retrieve dates from the above HTML snippet. All the dates are present in either of the two tags and need to Retrieve them all with a single XPATH

### **What have been tried so far:**

I am able to get the date values with two different xpath. One for the first tag `<TH class=.... >` and one for `<THstyle = ....>`

```
Xpath one : //TH[@class = 'abcd']
Xpath two : //TH[@height = '18'] 'Not sure if this is right
```

### **What is required:**

Only One xpath is to get date values from the above HTML.

1. Is this possible  'Bear with me on this, I am a beginner :)
2. If yes, requesting your guidance on arriving the same

## UPDATE :

First Up **Thanks much @Mathias Müller**. I tried but no luck. It returned 0 elements. It might be that i have missed something and not anything with xpath you suggested :). So i am posting an updated code here.. Vbscript & QTP. Please let me know if this is right and what am i missing here

Note : All these date values are in a webtable

```
Set odesc=Description.Create()
    odesc("micclass").value="WebElement" 
    odesc("xpath").value="//th[@class = 'abcd' or @height = 18]/text()" 

set test = Browser("asdfasdf").Page("asdfasdf").WebTable("xyz").ChildObjects(odesc)
    For i = 1 To test.count-1
        val=test(i).GetROProperty("innertext")
        MsgBox val
    Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a well-formed input document, use

```
//TH[@class = 'abcd' or @height = 18]/text()
```

which will yield (individual results separated by `-----`):

```
03 Mar 2014
-----------------------
27 Feb 2014
-----------------------
03 Jun 2014
-----------------------
12 Jun 2014
```

The path expression would also retrieve nodes where both attributes are present, e.g.

```
<TH class="abcd" style="WIDTH: 70%" height="18">03 Jun 2014</TH>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this .Remove the text from the XPath descriptive

```
Set odesc=Description.Create()
    odesc("micclass").value="WebElement" 
    odesc("xpath").value="//th[@class = 'abcd' or @height = 18]" 

set test = Browser("asdfasdf").Page("asdfasdf").WebTable("xyz").ChildObjects(odesc)
    For i = 1 To test.count-1
        val=test(i).GetROProperty("innertext")
        MsgBox val
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks much SaiKrishna :) When i remove text(), it fetches dates from tags with style attribute. `<TH style="WIDTH: 58%" height=18>27 Feb 2014</TH>`. Example it fetches me 27 Feb 2014 and not the entire thing

Comment: Innetext fetches the text and innerhtml or outerhtml gives the html value

Comment: I think my last comment is a bit confusing. sorry for that. The thing is it fetches date value. but only from one html tag as mentioned in the query. the one with style attribute and not the other (one with Class attribute)

Comment: does test.count returns 1 ?

Comment: I Fixed it :) Thank you :) Had issue with browser element. It works well with the xpath given by Mathias. Thanks much for the time and support :)